# Keep <text> element scaled inside <svg> with viewBox

Tags: html, xml, svg, text, layout

I'm trying to put some text as labels inside some scaled  elements, and the text is too big to fit in the container. What can I do here?

```
<div class="t_container">
  <div class="t_x" style="position: relative;">
    <svg position="absolute" viewBox="0 0 6 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="0.4"><title>Nov-21</title></rect>
        <text x="0.5" y="0.5" fill="red">A<text>
      </g>
    <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1"><title>Nov-22</title></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1"><title>Nov-23</title></rect>       
    <rect x="3" y="0" width="1" height="1"><title>Nov-24</title></rect>
    <rect x="4" y="0" width="1" height="1"><title>Nov-25</title></rect>       
    <rect x="5" y="0" width="1" height="1"><title>Nov-26</title></rect></svg>
</div>
```

Here is [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaepNw) with the result.

Comment: decrease the font size of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very small custom `viewport="0 0 6 1"` size. 6px - width, 1px - height, so the font can not be displayed with such parameters.

I increased the size of the viewBox 100 times `viewBox="0 0 600 100"`

Squares for clarity painted in different colors. You can change their coloring according to your choice.

The text is placed inside the squares. I hope that's exactly what you wanted when you used the command

`<title> Nov-24 </ title>` inside the squares.

But the command `<title>` in SVG is a system tooltip, the information from which appears when you hover the cursor. 
The size of the tooltip and its font can not be changed, so I added in the squares more tags `<text> ... </ text>`, the parameters of which you can change.

```html
<div class="t_container">
  <div class="t_x" style="position: relative;">
    <svg position="absolute"  viewBox="0 0 600 100" >
     <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40"><title>Nov-21</title></rect>
        <text x="35" y="75" font-size="36" fill="red">A</text>
      </g>
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="orange">
 <title>Nov-22</title></rect> 
   <text x="125" y="55" font-size="18" fill="white">Nov-22</text>

   <rect x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="orangered">
 <title>Nov-23</title></rect>     
  <text x="225" y="55" font-size="18" fill="white">Nov-23</text>
  
  
    <rect x="300" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green">
 <title>Nov-24</title></rect>
  <text x="325" y="55" font-size="18" fill="white">Nov-24</text>
  
    <rect x="400" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="dodgerblue">
 <title>Nov-25</title></rect>     
    <text x="425" y="55" font-size="18" fill="white">Nov-25</text>
 
    <rect x="500" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellowgreen">
 <title>Nov-26</title></rect> 
 <text x="525" y="55" font-size="18" fill="white">Nov-26</text>
 
 
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mark your answer. I did not realized that the small viewport will break something. Thanks!